# How to use AWK command

Tags: php, awk

Below is what I am trying to do:

1. There is one PHP variable which contains a string.

   ```
   $indexvalue='hotmail.com; spf=none (sender IP is 1.1.1.23)';
   ```
2. I want to use an AWK command to get value `none` and IP value `1.1.1.23` in two different PHP variables.

How can this be done?

Comment: Wait what. You have a string stored in a PHP variable and you want to use awk to parse it? Why?

Comment: why dont you use preg_match()?

Comment: Don't add a dependency on `awk` which may fail in systems not having awk.  Is the string _always_ of this exact format, with the same words (sender IP and spf=)? A regular expression is the right tool for this.

Answer (score 3):

it really depends on the format of your string. which bits are always going to be in there and what bit change a guess based on what I have here

`preg_match('/.*; spf=([^\s]*) \(sender IP is ([^)]*)\)/', $indexvalue, $matches);`

after which $matches contains

```
Array
(
    [0] => hotmail.com; spf=none (sender IP is 1.1.1.23)
    [1] => none
    [2] => 1.1.1.23
)
```

This assumes that spf= will always be present, that after the domain name there will be a ; and that the ip is announced by sender IP is.

Comment: Instead of the greedy `.*` I would recommend `spf=([^\s]*)` and `([^)]*)` respectively....